# How to create a React.js new window popup

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I want my cookies details to open in a new window popup in my Chrome browser when i click on it.

This is my code-

```
</div>
   <a href="javascript:window.open('','_self').close();">
      <label className="return"><T.span text='Cookies.Homepage' /></label>
   </a>
</div>
```

---

```
<Link to="/Cookies" target="_blank">
<T.span text='Footer.Cookies'/>
</Link>
```

But this always opens the cookies content in a new tab. How can i open it in a separate new window popup??

Answer (score 2):

To open the new window in an actual window, and not a tab, you need to pass in a specs parameter to window.open:

```
javascript:window.open('','_blank','height=600,width=400');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use blank instead of self

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('','_blank').close();">
```

Comment: Same effect. It opens in a new tab instead of popup.

Comment: I have tried this though - https://github.com/JakeGinnivan/react-popout
Installed a react popoup plugin. It is working fine now.

Comment: @Boris I also tried react popout plugin. But the issue I'm facing is with the callback when the popped window is closed. Function defined for 'onClosing' event is triggered when popup is loaded and doesn't trigger if the window is closed explicitly by user. Pls help.